# System.TypeLoadException Message=VTable setup of type Prism.Autofac.AutofacContainerExtension failed

Tags: xamarin, prism, autofac, vtable

After update to xamarin forms 3.6->4.2, prism.Autofac.Forms 7.0->7.1, and xamarin.android.support.% 28.0.0.1->28.0.0.3 I'm getting

System.TypeLoadException
Message=VTable setup of type Prism.Autofac.AutofacContainerExtension failed

stack trace:

at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize () [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:130
at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal () [0x00006] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:84
at Prism.PrismApplicationBase..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer, System.Boolean setFormsDependencyResolver) [0x00038] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:75
at Prism.PrismApplicationBase..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:57
at Prism.Autofac.PrismApplication..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Autofac.Forms\PrismApplication.cs:30
at DisMobi.App..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer initializer) [0x00000] in C:...........\App.xaml.cs:28
at xxxxxx.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00079] in C:..........\xxxxxx.Android\MainActivity.cs:35
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in :0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.3(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: In order to help you we will need more more information. Could you post at least the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: added the stack trace

Comment: Have you tried checking out a clean copy of the source? This kind of errors is most likely some wrong dlls. Also, have you checked all references of all projects in the solution?

Comment: Could be... I'm still trying, instaling and uninstalling NuGets to find the newest that works and checking the code. Pre-update version of code works fine...

Comment: Definitly an issue with autofac update... Found some info about prism and autofac so maybe it will be best to keep the current version of prism.autofac.forms or change container

Comment: Even the prism.plugin.popups is generating the same issue...